# How to extract non-uppercase string elements for first and last names?

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

I have strings of the form

```
NAME Firstame
```

and I would like to get the `Firstname` part. The string can be more complicated (`LAST LAST2 First First2`). The rule is that uppercase elements are the last name and the rest is the first name. We can assume that the first part will be upper case (= last name) and when it starts to be mixed case it is the first name until the end.

I am sure that the right regex combination of `[A-Z]` and `\w` would work. The best I came up with is

```
import re
re.findall('[A-Z]*\w+', 'LAST LAST2 First First2')
```

but it returns *almost* the right solution (`['LAST', 'LAST2', 'First', 'First2']`) :)

What would be a good way to extract this first name(s) in Python as one string?

Comment: How about using `'[A-Z][a-z]+'` as pattern?

Comment: A must read [article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Also, `\w` matches more than you think, it will match lower and uppercase letters, digits and underscore `_`.

Comment: @HamZa: I know this article (there is a similar one on [dates](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)) - in my case this is fortunately just a quick test which can break (yes, such quick tests then turn into the Mars Rover navigation system or something but that's another story :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With regex:**

```
import re
s = 'LAST LAST2 First First2'
print re.search("[A-Z][a-z].*$",s).group().split()
```

- `[A-Z]` match a single character present in the range between A and Z
  (case sensitive)
- `[a-z]` match a single character present in the
  range between a and z (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character
  (except newline) Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as
  many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `$` assert
  position at end of the string

**Non-regex**

```
s = 'LAST LAST2 First First2'
print [i for i in s.split() if not i.isupper()]
```

**[out]:**

```
['First', 'First2']
```

Comment: Thanks - the non-regex one is great (I have to learn about these `[...]` constructions which turn beautiful Python code into cryptic Perl-like one :))

Comment: they're call list comprehension. Coming from C/C++ background, at first i thought it's magic. Now i know it's "black" magic that works wonders.

Comment: Same for me. I was about to edit my comment to give the right name you mentioned (and a [pointer to the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose a non-regex solution:

```
string = 'LAST LAST2 First First2'
words = string.split(' ') # equals ['LAST', 'LAST2', 'First', 'First2']
result = []
for word in words:
    if not word.isupper():
        result.append(word)
print(' '.join(result))
```

Result:

```
First First2
```

Comment: You are ahead of me(( If you could do something simply without regexp I think it's better to do that without them

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import re
re.findall('\b[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]+', 'LAST LAST2 First First2')
```

this will result in:

```
# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'First', u'First2']
```

Comment: The code cause an exception: `sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern`

Comment: you are right, i forgot that python doesnt like (?-i) to declare case sensitivity. have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Will this code help you:

```
re.search("[A-Z][a-z].*$","LAST LAST2 First First2").group()
```

Or it can be more robust:

```
re.search("(?<= )[A-Z][^A-Z][\w|\s]*$","LAST LAST2 First First2").group()
```